# Existence and uniqueness without ellipticity condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, coercive

Consider a function $a:[0,1]\to[0,\infty)$, e.g., $a(x)=x$. Are there existence theorems for equations of the form:
\begin{align*}
u-\big(a(x)u_x\big)_x=f(x) ?
\end{align*}
what are the boundary conditions to be assumed, if for example $a$ vanishes at $0$? What if $a$ vanishes on an open subset of $(0,1)$ or on, let's say $[0,1/2)$. If $a\in C^1$ and $f\in L^2$, what is the regularity of $u$? here its is not assumed the ellipticity condition for $a$.

What about parabolic equations,
\begin{align*}
u_t-\big(a(x)u_x\big)_x=f(x,t) ?
\end{align*}

Is there any standard reference for this? What about $n$-dimensional case, where $a$ semi-positive definite matrix, but not necessarily a positive-definite one?

Comment: For parabolic equations I don't think this matters as much, as all you need are bounds on the spectra of the elliptic part, not anything related to the dimensionality of eigenspaces (which is impacted by loss of ellipticity).